# Bad USB not recognized by Finder

Tags: usb, bug, catalina

I have a 15 GB USB that I want to use as a macOS installer, and it got corrupted.

I tried to reset it, but Finder and the normal Disk Utility does not recognize it, the Recovery Disk Utility loops on loading drives and Terminal throws an error if I tried to reset it.

What can I do to make it work again?

Answer (score 1):

When I run into this kind of problem, I first identify the device with:

```
diskutil list
```

(e.g., /dev/disk3 -- BE SURE TO GET THE CORRECT DEVICE OR YOU WILL HAVE DATA LOSS)

Then I use the `dd` command to zero it out.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk3 bs=8M
```

I hardly ever wait to completion, rather just a few seconds (maybe 10-15) and then press Control-C to stop it. This is just enough to wipe out everything at the start of the device that tells how it's formatted.

At that point, I go back into Disk Utility, insert the device, and repartition it, putting on a new formatted filesystem.

Comment: 8M gives an unvalid character. Putting only 8 will give me dd: /dev/disk5: Resource busy